# Is this question a better fit for SO?

Tags: discussion

I always struggle on deciding if a question is a good fit for here or for it would be better in SO.

Is [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/100963/what-is-the-difference-between-public-dependency-and-dba-dependencies) a good fit for SE.DA or It would be better if post it in SO?

After [reading the help](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), It doesn't seem a good fit for here, but I am not sure it is a SO question either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question would be reasonable for DBA.SE - in fact a better fit for DBA.SE as it's not actually a question related to programming but is a actually a question about a database related topic.

Plus, we have a few Oracle wonks here who may well know the answer to your question.